# Vue.js, props and scoped slots

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am coming from a React world. In React, a component which receives children can easily alter them (modify or add props) before they render. I have not found a way to do this in VueJS after hours of reading the docs and searching on forums.

Here is some code:

```
<FormField :fieldName="myFieldName">
    <NumericInput 
        :value="2"
    ></NumericInput>
</FormField>
```

I want `FormField` to pass the `fieldName` to `NumercInput`:

```
export default class FormField {
    @Prop()
    private fieldName!: string;
}

<template>
    <div class="form-field">
        <slot :fieldName="fieldName"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

But it doesn't work. `NumericInput` does not received the name. According to the docs, I should do as follow:

```
<FormField :fieldName="myFieldName">
    <template v-slot="slotProps">
        <NumericInput 
            :fieldName="slotProps.fieldName"
            :value="2"
        ></NumericInput>
    </template>
</FormField>
```

It does work. But I don't want the grand-parent to be responsible of wiring props between `FormField` and `NumericInput`. I want `FormField` to decide whether and how it should pass down `fieldName` to `NumericInput`. How do I do that? I also do not understand why do I have to specify the binding of `fieldName` on `NumericInput` and also on the `slot` for it to work?

In React I can just iterate the children with `React.children` and then add or modify the props.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use props to pass data from a parent to a child if that it what your after
an example for verification
<html>
  <head>
    <title>props and components</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="subText">
        <storage />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      Vue.component('storage', {
        data() {
          return {
            message: 'hi from storage component',
            message2: 'hi from product component',
          }
        },
        template: `
        <div>
            {{ message }}
            <product :message2="message2" />
        </div>`,
      })

      Vue.component('product', {
        props: {
          message2: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
        },
        template: `
       <div>
        {{ message2 }}
        </div>
       `,
      })

      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a basic parent-child prop passing thing. Don't use v-slot for now.

```
<FormField>
        <NumericInput 
            :fieldName="thisWillBePropToChild"
        ></NumericInput>
</FormField>
```

In FormField component, declare

```
data () {
    return { childFieldName: '' }
},
props: ['fieldName']
```

Modify your fieldName like

```
this.childFieldName = this.fieldName
```

In NumericInput component, declare

```
props: ['childFieldName']
```

and access using, anywhere in the NumericInput component

```
this.childFieldName
```

Taken two different names, since you need to modify the prop and then send. Mutating prop directly is not recommended.

If you want to change any prop and make it reactive in your child component (as states in React), you will use data(can say state in React) properties.

Comment: I want FormFIeld to also receive fieldName, and don't want to duplicate the code. My example is very minimal but in my real app fieldName should be passed to FormField, then FormField should alter it and pass it down to NumericInput.

Comment: I have edited as per your requirement, please try. You need to declare the props you are going to receive in each component. If you don't want to modify, you can directly send the child with the same name